# Error creating an SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl

During the creation of a SSL certificate this error occurs:

```
problem creating object tsa_policy1=1.2.3.4.1
13964:error:08064066:object identifier routines:OBJ_create:oid exists:crypto\objects\obj_dat.c:690:
error in req
```

This is what I've done

```
set RANDFILE=c:\certificate\.rnd
set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
C:\openssl-win64\bin\openssl.exe
genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
```

I've entered a passphrase and then:

```
req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

and then It shows me the error.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Figured It out. Don't install OpenSSl version 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade OPENSSL Version to 1.0.2o

Follow this guide: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/